# Is this "good practice" to do in AS3 (about using Grand Events)?

Tags: actionscript-3

first I'd like to thank you for taking the time to read my question.
So, I've made a little flash game(can't really call it a game), anyway at one point I'm checking for if 2 objects hit each other. So to sum it up here's the code

```
public function loop(e:Event):void
{
    y += vx;
    if(y > stageRef.stageHeight || y < 0)
        removeSelf();
    if(hitTestObject(target.hit))
    {
        removeSelf();
        stageRef.dispatchEvent(new GameOverEvent(GameOverEvent.DEAD)); // <--
        stageRef.addChild(new SmallImplosion(stageRef, x, y));
    }
}
```

So, when they collide, one object dispatches an event, there is no problem with the code, it works, but I would like to know if it's good to make handle it this way. stageRef is the reference to stage, both classes have it.

And my other class catches that event and it triggers a function, like this:

```
stageRef.addEventListener(GameOverEvent.DEAD, takeHit, false, 0, true);
```

The question is, is this a good way to handle it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When implementing the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), each of the participating objects has a clear role: One is the subject, who is the object where the action is happening, while the other is the observer, who listenes for events on the subjects. In Flash, any object can be the observer, as you pass the handling function to the subscribe-method. Subjects however implement [IEventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html) and provide the necessary methods to subscribe to the subject. There is also the standard implementation [EventDispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html) which already implements the necessary methods (and many types are subtypes of it).

Now back to your question; you are essentially bringing in a third party, the stage where the events are broadcasted on. Instead of having the events that are local to the subject dispatched on the subject itself, you are dispatching them over the global stage, and all observers have to listen to the stage instead of the subject itself.

This is generally not what you should do. Every subject (IEventDispatcher) should only dispatch its own events. Just like you receive a click event from the button that is clicked, you’d receive a GameOverEvent from the object that triggers it.

Comment: Thanks, still, is it a good method to handle it that way by doing event listeners, or would be calling classname.functionName(); be better?

Comment: You mean make the subject call the object that is actually listening directly? No, I don’t think that would be better. The observer pattern allows for loose coupling, so that the subject does not necessarily know what objects are listening to it. Any object that is interested should just start listen to it, so the only the listener knows about the subject but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

From the name `GameOverEvent`, I believe a bit of significance is implied.  Since there's plenty to do at the end of a game, I feel it's appropriate for your stage to listen for an event such as this.

However, don't use this technique to handle any smaller systems.  For example, if the collision only dealt some damage to the player (I don't know if this even makes sense in the context of your game but roll with me here) then it would be better to have the classes that check for collisions and the classes that handle health to interact directly with one another instead of firing these "*Grand Events*".

Comment: Thank you for making it a bit more clear, as you can see I'm still a beginner. If you don't mind can you tell me which method it's best to use to let them "interact directly" (I know there isn't a "best" method but I want to hear your opinion), for smaller systems of course.

Comment: This depends a lot on how you architect your system but, using the "Dealing Damage" example:  Let's say you have a class `CollisionHandler` that, every frame, checks all your collision conditions and then dispatches instructions on how to handle those collisions. Now lets say you have your player's info stored in a class called `Player` and you've initialize and instance with the name `plyr`.  Instead of `CollisionHandler` dispatching an event and giving `plyr` and event listener, it would be more efficient to store a reference to `plyr` in `CollisionHandler` and modify `plyr`'s data directly.

Comment: I really hate to be annoying, but please answer me one more thing. Does this mean that I should use plyr.functionName(); ? Thank you a lot again!

Comment: Yup! I ran out of space in the last comment :P